# Error when trying to compile golang when using package from github

Tags: go, github, compilation, package

I'm trying to install the package robotgo on my laptop. I used the command `go get github.com/go-vgo/robotgo` to download and install it

I then run this code, but it fails to compile and returns the error below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/go-vgo/robotgo"
)

func main() {
    x, y := robotgo.GetMousePos()
    fmt.Println("pos: ", x, y)
}
```

Error:

```
# command-line-arguments
C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `default_logger':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../hook/windows/../logger_c.h:39: undefined reference to `__getreent'
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../hook/windows/../logger_c.h:32: undefined reference to `__getreent'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `loggerProc':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/pub.h:97: undefined reference to `__getreent'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `eb_port_retain':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:426: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `eb_port_wait':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:453: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `port_list_signal_first':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:648: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `cleanup_ops':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:857: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `eb_chan_retain':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:777: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `eb_assert_print':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:146: undefined reference to `__getreent'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `eb_port_create':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:390: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `eb_port_free':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:358: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:349: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `eb_port_release':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:432: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `eb_port_signal':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:439: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `cleanup_ops':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:866: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:866: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `port_list_signal_first':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:651: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:651: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `recv_unbuf':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:1210: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o:C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:1180: more undefined references to `sched_yield' follow
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `try_op':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:1249: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `eb_chan_release':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:783: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `eb_chan_close':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:796: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `port_list_signal_first':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:651: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:651: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `eb_chan_close':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:791: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `eb_chan_buf_cap':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:830: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `eb_chan_buf_len':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:843: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:835: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `cleanup_ops':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:866: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:866: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `recv_unbuf':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:1210: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:1180: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `port_list_signal_first':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:651: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o:C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:620: more undefined references to `sched_yield' follow
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `try_op':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:1249: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `port_list_add':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:597: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `port_list_signal_first':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:651: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:651: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:651: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:651: undefined reference to `sched_yield'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `port_list_add':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:592: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:591: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `port_list_signal_first':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:648: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `eb_chan_select_list':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:1299: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `port_list_rm':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:617: undefined reference to `__assert_func'
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o:C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/../chan/eb_chan.h:616: more undefined references to `__assert_func' follow
C:\Users\sieea\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-143133203\000004.o: In function `dispatch_proc':
C:\Users\sieea\go\src\github.com\robotn\gohook/event/dispatch_proc.h:66: undefined reference to `__getreent'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have MinGW-W64 in my system path and that code and library works on my desktop pc, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work on my laptop. I've reinstalled MinGW, Go, and Goland multiple times to attempt to get it to work but I don't know what the problem is.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: have you installed gcc

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/issues/174, e.g.: "Looking more at the variables above I’m pretty sure you are on a 64bit architecture but using a C compiler in 32 bit mode"

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your MinGW installation with https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/

I've struggled with another cgo package on Windows a couple of days ago, trying out several different MinGW versions and so on. Somewhere on the net I've found that this distributive of GCC works well with cgo on Win. Installed it and everything does work like a charm!

I know it's not a very detailed answer, but if you just need it to work - might help.